# MPI_BCAST in fortran not working on new cluster

Tags: fortran, mpi

I have a working code that I have been using on an old cluster more than a year ago. This year, I want to use this code again, however, the cluster is different, and results became meaningless. I know the specifics of this cluster, but it's quite hard to find the ones from that old cluster.

I have been able to narrow the problem to a `MPI_BCAST` call:

```
    if (rang.eq.0) print*, "psi for rang0 = ", psi
    CALL MPI_BCAST (psi, NSITES, MPI_DOUBLE_COMPLEX,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,code)
    if (rang.eq.1) print*, "psi for rang1 = ", psi
```

Before, this worked fine, and `psi` was correctly distributed over all ranks.

Now, on rank `1`, on this new cluster, I get the initial value of `psi` (complex array of zeros), without it being updated with the value from rank `0` (non-zero values).

`Module list` gives me

1) intel/13.0.1    2) openmpi/1.8.1

for the compiler that is being used on this new cluster.

I cannot access the old cluster, so cannot check which compilers were loaded. Nevertheless, it might have been this:

`which mpif90
/opt/mpi/bullxmpi/1.1.16.5/bin/mpif90`,

as I found this snippet in one of my old emails.

So, has MPI_BCAST usage changed over the years?
I also did a test where I added a `MPI_BARRIER`, just to be sure, but to no avail.

Edits for minimal example reproducing the error (on this new cluster).

```
    PROGRAM minimal
    use mpi
    IMPLICIT NONE
    INTEGER :: NSITES, rang, i, code
    DOUBLE COMPLEX , DIMENSION (:), allocatable :: psi
    DOUBLE PRECISION ralpha, PI, val
    INTEGER :: NB_PROCS 

    CALL MPI_INIT(code)
    call MPI_COMM_SIZE (MPI_COMM_WORLD,nb_procs,code)
    call MPI_COMM_RANK (MPI_COMM_WORLD,rang,code)

    PI = 4.d0*atan(1.d0)

    NSITES = 10

    allocate (psi (NSITES) )

    DO i = 1, NSITES
      psi(i) = (0.0d0, 0.0d0)
    END DO

    val = 1.0 / dsqrt(1.0d0 * NSITES)

    DO i = 1, NSITES
      IF (rang.eq.0) THEN
           CALL RANDOM_NUMBER (ralpha)
           psi (i) = exp (2.0d0 * PI * (0.0d0, 1.0d0) * ralpha)    &
                   * val
      ENDIF
    ENDDO

    CALL MPI_BCAST (psi, NSITES, MPI_DOUBLE_COMPLEX,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,code)
    if (rang.eq.1) print*, "psi for rang1 = ", psi

    CALL MPI_FINALIZE(code)

    END program minimal
```

I have checked this code on my local macbook, there it works just fine.

Comment: You say you narrow it down to that call, but can you make a [mcve] for us?  Without that we have to make an awful lot of assumptions about declarations and the like.

Comment: To quickly answer your last question no MPI_BCAST hasn't changed. To say more as Francescalus says please show us a complete program demonstrating the problem.

Comment: It is quite possible that your code has always been buggy, but only now it causes sone difference. Nothing unussual, but we have to see the code.

Comment: Will try to compile such example in the evening. Sorry about that.

Comment: This minimal example seems to reproduce the error. The values printed out after the BCAST are all zeros, instead of the expected non-zero ones coming from rank 1.

Comment: Still not working. And my original code included the implicit none (surprised though that it didn't complain about not declaring the MPI_* variables on the other cluster, while it does here when I add implicit none).

Comment: Yes, I figured that out. Just did add use mpi (like is the case in my real code). Sorry, went a bit fast with this minimal code. Still, the output is the same, all zeros...

Comment: I just installed mpif90 on my local machine, and ran the above minimal code. It produces the expected result (non-zero values). So, I still think this is related to the specifics of the compilers...

Comment: If your MPI installation is corrupted, it will be difficult to give you any help. You can try to reinstall it...

Comment: I have informed the administrators of the cluster, I cannot change their installation. Still, on the cluster, they do have several versions available through `module avail`, and have tried several of the `openmpi` ones. But as you say, it may be related to the actual `mpi` library... I Could of course install everything mpi related from scratch on my /home/ directory, but that is not really considered good practice on such HPC infrastructure. Unless no one has experiences similar problem, I suppose I'll have to rely on the cluster IT team. Will keep you posted.

Comment: The module system will probably give you different mpi libraries, so I am very confused as to what is going on. Your code looks good to me despite some slightly archaic usage, and works in the sense of not giving zeros on my laptop.

Comment: If I were you I would remove the random number generation call and use instead deterministic code (e.g. let psi[i] = (i,i)). I would also remove the extra variables pi and val. Then check again the result and let your sysadmin know that this very simple example fails on the setup and you need help getting it to work correctly.

Comment: So, sysadmin just finished helping me, actually. The culprit was the module loaded by default. I tried some others, but forgot changing my submission script where modules are loaded again. So, I only changed the module at compilation time, but not at run time. Bottom line, corrupted module loaded by default, stupid me not properly switching to other module to solve the problem on my own.

Comment: What should I do for this question? I don't think it will benefit the community, as it was a one time problem. What about adding an answer? And what about the open bounty?

Comment: You can always answer it yourself, with basically that 2nd last comment you made.  If there are any specific modules/versions that were the culprit, you could list them too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The culprit was the module loaded by default (openmpi/1.8.1).

First, I tried some others, but forgot changing my submission script where modules were loaded again. So, I only changed the module at compilation time, but not at run time.

Bottom line, corrupted module loaded by default, stupid me not properly switching to other module to solve the problem on my own.

It works now with openmpi/1.8.4.